# How to find Intersection of Two Curves

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I need to find the intersection of curves $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1 $ and $x + y=0$ 
So using $x =-y$ . I get  $2y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and this curve is an ellipse in $y-z$ plane.

However my book says the answer is a circle .

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $2y^2 + z^2 = 1$ is indeed an ellipse in the $y-z$ plane but the intersecion is in the space between a sphere and a plane through the origin which is indeed a circle.

We can use a parametric representation of the circle

- $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$
- $x+y=0$

by

- $x=t$
- $y=-t$
- $z=\pm\sqrt{1-2t^2}$

with $1-2t^2 \ge 0 \implies -\frac{\sqrt 2}2\le t \le\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.

Comment: So, umm just as a another question , what will be the center and radius of this circle ?

Comment: @zeroflank By symmetry and by parametrization we see that the center is $(0,0)$ and the radius is $1$. We are slicing the unit sphere with a verical plane containing the line $y=-x$.